# Create a dynamic Tray Icon with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, system-tray, trayicon, tray

I am trying to create a Tray icon with Python on Ubuntu Linux (this is not important, but it is for more details). I need my small system to show an Icon (Image) according to the result (Boolean) returned from a method. All this within an **infinite loop**, **checking every 5 minutes**, ie a status icon that updates according to the return of the method.

I tried with several different libraries, such as: **`PyQt5.QtGui`**, **`PyQt5.QtWidgets`**, **`PySimpleGUIQt`**, **`pystray`**. All of these execute a command that prevents the infinite loop from running after the first iteration. The command is: **`app.exec_()`**

Code example:

```
def check_network_status():
      try:
          requests.get('http://google.com.br/')
          return True
      excepte:       
          return False

while True:    
  if check_network_status():
      # show online icon
  else:
      # show offline icon
```

thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/adanced-ui-features/system-tray-mac-menu-bar-applications-pyqt/) is what you're looking for?

Comment: don't use infinity loop in any GUI framework. Most GUI has some method to run code periodically and not block other elements (like `mainloop`/`event loop` which has to loop all time). As I remeber `PyQt` has `QTimer` for this.

Comment: @nathancy, I tried wth this one, but I can't because I'm using infinite loop. I will try using this tutorial again, matching the furas tip. Thanks for the help from both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve using QTimer of PyQT. The question below is exactly what I needed:

[threading for tray icon application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851544/threading-for-tray-icon-application)